# Collatz Conjecture and printing statements

Tags: python, syntax, collatz

I am trying to create a simple program to apply the statement of the Collatz Conjecture to an integer that the user can enter, I have:

```
def collatz(n):
    print n,
    if n % 2 ==0:
        n = n / 2
    elif n == 0:
        Print "Collatz Conjecture true for" , 'n'
    else:
        n = n *3 + 1

input("\n\nInsert a positive integer:")
def collatz(n)
```

However it is saying there is a syntax error in the line:

```
Print "Collatz Conjecture true for" , 'n'
```

I can't see what mistake ther is in this line.

Also as I haven't been able to test it yet, does this look as though it will work ok?

Comment: After you fix the syntax errors, you'll want to add a [loop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Comment: You'll also want to define `n` somewhere, preferably as the result of `input()` (which should be `raw_input()` anyway, since you're obviously on Python 2). Did you read at least a bit of the Python tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

Python is case sensitive. Use "print" not "Print".

Answer (score 3):

Well, your syntax error is that python is case-sensitive, so you need `print` rather than `Print`.

But you've got more problems:

- `'n'` prints the string `n`. I think what you want is `n` to print the value of the variable (or if not, then you can just make a single string "... true for n").
- Finally (I think), in order to run the function `collatz`, you don't need the `def`; that's just for the definition.

Comment: No need for the “(I think)”; it indeed is that way.

Comment: Actually, I put in 'I think' to modify 'finally', since I wasn't sure there weren't more problems!

Comment: Ah, okay. You can replace that with “also”, because without a loop (or recursion), the function will only do the first step of the calculation.

Comment: Oh so is collatz a built in function? I'm confused in that respect.

Comment: George, no I meant you don't need the `def` on the final line, after you've *defined* it, in order to *use* it.

Answer (score 2):

More problems:

1. The stopping condition should be `n == 1`, not `n == 0`.
2. You have to recur or iterate, as is you're only making one step.
3. Check the input, make sure it really is a positive number.

Comment: Good point about it being 1 and 0, also I am working through the tutorial so short of using abs() and int() I'm not sure what to do for step 3.

Also how should it be modified to iterate?

Comment: Also I've eliminated elif n == 1 in favour of while n > 1

Comment: For the input check, `if n < 1:` and then you can a) complain b) transform the input, whatever you think is better. What syntax error? If you replace the entire if/elif/else construct with `while n > 1:`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def collatz_steps(n):
    steps=0
    if n==1:
        return 0 
    else:
        while n!=1:
            if n%2==0:
                n=n/2
                steps+=1
            else:
                n = 3*n+1
                steps+=1
        return steps
```

Comment: This example is not aligned properly.